# Google maps embedding

Tags: google-maps

This is what google maps suggests me to use for embedding the map to my site:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2964.797839390929!2d21.414694!3d42.004614!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1354145ab3a48fd5%3A0x9f3ee09c5eb92ad9!2sRestaurant+Jana!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1409184591679" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

This is the point it should display: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Restaurant+Jana/@42.004614,21.414694,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x9f3ee09c5eb92ad9?hl=en-US

But this is how it looks:

[image]

0 zoom and map is not fully loaded. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o232r1yu/ ???  it fully...

Comment: oh zoom = 0  is minimum of zoom of google map. Width of map label < width of iframe, it background of google map :D

Comment: Is this hidden on page load?  It is acting like the iframe had zero size when the map was initialized.

Comment: But if it is hidden initially, the [problem is reproduced](http://jsfiddle.net/o232r1yu/3/)

Comment: @geocodezip you are right, map is in an inactive tab hidden with display: none, which gets the display: block declaration when  selected. I did not think that it would affect the iframe's size.

Comment: display: none causes the browser to return zero for the size of that on page load.  When the map is initialized in a zero-sized div you get the behavior you see (the center is in the top left corner, grey space around the loaded tiles), one possible solution is to render it out of view but with the correct size and move it to the correct place when you want it to become visible.